# Angular - Find type of form groups controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following reactive form. What I want to do is to make a copy of a part of the form and turn it into a new one.

```
 this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            group: this.formBuilder.group({
                name: 'Zero',
                lastName: 'Zeroo'
            }),
            name: 'One',
            array: this.formBuilder.array([
                { name: 'two'},
                { name: 'three'}
                ])
        });
```

With the following code, I try to do the copy.

```
    let formControlKeys = Object.keys(this.myForm.value);
    this.myCopyForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
    for (let key of formControlKeys){
              console.log(typeof this.myForm.controls[key]);
              // prints object

              // code to create new FormControl / FormGroup / FormArray 
              // inside myCopyForm according to type got above
          }
```

The required functionality is to get the `reactive-form` type and not only 
`object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. The catch here is that when you try to `console.log` the type of something using the `typeof` keyword, you are actually getting the run-time Javascript type of that thing, which in this case is an `object`. Typescript is a *compile-to-JS* language, meaning that all those fancy types and interfaces and such are *only* used for static type checking. When the your code gets to the browser, all of that type information is gone and you're looking and plain old Javascript.

So, the type of `this.myForm.controls[key]` at the point you're referencing it in the code actually is what you want, [an `AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl). You can use those controls to build a copy of your form, like so:

```
this.copyForm = new FormGroup({});
for (let key of Object.keys(this.myForm.value)) {
  const control = this.myForm.controls[key]; // AbstractControl
  this.copyForm.addControl(key, control);
}
```

More information on the `FormGroup` API can be found here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Take a look at this plunker. The copy works, but the copy is now connected to the input and not the original. Any idea why this happens? (Change the value at the input)
https://plnkr.co/edit/axpaxFyy3LfNNXhiCUV6?p=preview

Comment: Apparently, it is still a reference to an object, so it makes sense in a way for the copy to obtain the connection. but why the original loses it?

Comment: No problem :) Check out this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/POZuk543qAsrkDSd8Zgd?p=preview. The issue with the first solution is that it's pointing the control to a different parent, but keeps the same control. You want to create a copy of the control itself, then attach the copy to the new parent. But you'll notice that with this new plunkr, it's not quite the same. You will need to do a "deep copy" which will involve applying this technique recursively.